# Handling json string in powershell to execute in bash

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

We are creating a script to automate a service and for that we need to call a rest service ([az rest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively#rest-api-command---az-rest) from Azure CLI). We created an object in **powershell** which is converted to jason and passed to the REST call. Thing is, the REST works only with single quotes in the beginning of the body, like image below:

[image]

Because we use `ConvertTo-Json` twice (once for the conversion the other one to escape double quotes) we get the following string, which is fine:

`"{\"preAuthorizedApplications\":[{\"permissionIds\...":`

Here I need the first and last double quotes to be replaced by single quotes. Is there an easier way to do that other than using replace?

Comment: Do you mean `"'{0}'" -f $json.Trim('"')` ?

Comment: This did the trick

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Comment: Hi @singhh-msft. Sorry I didn't get back. No, it doesnt. Executing `az rest` in powershell seems like does not work so good because of the pythong compiler and escape character hell issue...at least it didn't work for me without using single quotes in the beginning of the json body. but I'm new in powershell...so I might have done something wrongly...

Comment: Did you try this same script?

Comment: @singhh-msft - yes, it does not work. I get bad request when array has more than one item...I have a complex json object, not only a string like in your example

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Out-String` for this use case of yours:

```
$json = @"
{
"Url": 'https://google.com'
}
"@
$object = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$objectString = $object.Url | Out-String

az rest --method GET --uri $objectString


$json1 = @"
{
"web": {"redirectUris": ["https://myapp.com"] }
}
"@

$object = $json1 | ConvertFrom-Json
$webString = $object.web | Out-String

az rest --method PATCH --uri $object.Url --body $webString
```